# Is it possible to post a poll with a picture in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I know how to post a poll in a Facebook group, but it seems not to be possible to add a picture in the poll question. Would there be a workaround, such as entering an URL of a picture that gets replaced by the actual picture, or HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

I think Facebook may be testing out an image based poll function, have a look at  the following example :
https://www.facebook.com/wongmjane/posts/1967658150230313?pnref=story
[image]

Theres another example facebook image poll here: https://www.facebook.com/thenextweb/posts/10155732517028523

**UPDATE**  As of 1st Dec 2017, it looks like Facebook have rolled this feature out to everyone now. Image polls seem to be limited to personal accounts for now.

Answer (score 0):

For that feature use TinyPic, upload your image there and TinyPic will deliver you link which you can copy and paste to your poll

Comment: And will the pictures be displayed in the poll after you've entered the url?

Comment: Yes. Some websites use TinyPic because they don't have enough spaces for hosting their own picture